# Perfectly uncorrupted USB formatted FAT32 is RAW on Windows

Tags: windows, partitioning, filesystems, usb-flash-drive

My USB key is detected as RAW on Windows, but works perfectly on Linux, or anything else where it's detected as FAT32 and everything works. I don't want to reformat it because it's hi-speed USB2 and it's 32GB.

The partition is correctly recognized as FAT32 in partitioning tools like EaseUS, MiniTool or Active@ that can all list files in the partition (but not show the content), which means it's really FAT32 and it's not corrupted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After trying some buttons in MiniTool partition editor (any other tool like EaseUS or Testdisk would work) I saw that the partition had its "Partition Type ID" field set as 0x0B (FAT32). I tried setting it to 0x0C (FAT32 LBA) and immediately after applying the changes, the drive appeared in the Windows Explorer as FAT32 and everything was working correctly.